# get Person Info with Google + / PlusClient

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm trying to get basic info of Google+ user to login in my app.

I can connect and get the account name :

```
String email = mPlusClient.getAccountName(); // This works, gives me the email
```

Then I try to get more info with :

```
        mPlusClient.loadVisiblePeople(new OnPeopleLoadedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult status,
                PersonBuffer personBuffer, String nextPageToken) {

            Log.i("", "persons loaded result = " + status.toString()
                    + ", personsCount = " + personBuffer.getCount()
                    + ", token = " + nextPageToken);
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Iterator<Person> itP = personBuffer.iterator();
                while (itP.hasNext()) {
                    Person person = itP.next();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), person.getNickname(), 5).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, null);
```

I can get friends info

```
persons loaded result = ConnectionResult{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}, personsCount = 15, token = null
```

But if I can't find how to get personal info...

When I try :

```
    Person p = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson();
```

p is null,

when I try:

```
mPlusClient.loadPerson(this, "me");
```

loadPerson is not recognized

So I don't know how to do it....

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try below code to get profile information of current user:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .addApi(Plus.API)
                            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                            .build();

if(mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
                if(Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null){
                    Person mCurrentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                    String displayName = mCurrentPerson.getDisplayName();
                    int mUserIdOfCurrentUser = mCurrentPerson.getId();
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG_LOAD_VISIBLE_PEOPLE, "DisplayName: "+displayName);
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG_LOAD_VISIBLE_PEOPLE,"Id: "+ mCurrentPerson.getId());
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG_LOAD_VISIBLE_PEOPLE,"Image: "+mCurrentPerson.getImage().getUrl());
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG_LOAD_VISIBLE_PEOPLE,"List of Urls: "+mCurrentPerson.getUrls());
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG_LOAD_VISIBLE_PEOPLE,"Current Url: "+mCurrentPerson.getUrl());
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG_LOAD_VISIBLE_PEOPLE,"Cover: "+mCurrentPerson.getCover());
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG_LOAD_VISIBLE_PEOPLE,"Object type: "+mCurrentPerson.getObjectType());
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG_LOAD_VISIBLE_PEOPLE,"User Id : "+mUserIdOfCurrentUser);
                }
```

Comment: I migrate plusClient to GoogleApiClient with this tutorial : http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2014/02/migrating-from-plusclient-to.html but I still have the problem, getCurrentPerson return null

Comment: What value you are getting for mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .addApi(Plus.API)
                            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                            .build(); .... if you are getting mGoogleApiClient object properly then with the code snippet that I have provided you should not have any problem. First of all tell me while signing in does it shows you a screen of consent and sign in?

Comment: my mGoogleApiClient is an object, it is not null, and Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mPlusClient) is working. Right now, I have no screen of consent and sign in, but I don't remember if I had the first time...

Comment: Person mCurrentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient); If mGoogleApiClient is not null, then this line will also work, please check out again. Have you added your email id and Product name in Developers Console --> Project --> APis and Authentication --> Consent screen --> then save. and after that if everything goes fine, then uninstall and re-install your app in device, consent screen will be shown for signing in.

Comment: now it is working. I forgot to add Google + Api in google console ! Tx for your help!!!

Comment: Oooh that was the basic step you must do..How could you forget! Fine its never late when you can finally solve your problem!

Answer (score 2):

May be your Signature is diffrent??

May be , you are using CUSTOM.keystore(Release Keystore) SHA1 . So i suggest you should use DEBUG SHA1 for google console. Just Add DEBUG keystore  SHA1 on google console.  It will work as it did for me